# What the ODataConventionModelBuilder.GetEdmModel() returns?

Tags: odata

```
ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
builder.EntitySet<Product>("Products");
return builder.GetEdmModel();
```

In above code what the method GetEdmModel() will return ?

Answer (score 1):

`ODataConventionModelBuilder.GetEdmModel` returns an object that implements `IEdmModel`. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.odata.builder.odataconventionmodelbuilder.getedmmodel(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Http.OData.Builder.ODataConventionModelBuilder.GetEdmModel) for details.